# C# WPF error XDG0062 "ContextMenu" не может иметь логического или визуального родителя

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Fill="#000000FF" Panel.ZIndex="1" x:Name="canvas_main" MouseRightButtonDown="func_rc_menu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Image Panel.ZIndex="0" Margin="20,20,20,20" Source="/img.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <ContextMenu x:Name="test">
            <MenuItem Header="test"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid>
```

1 ошибка:

> Ошибка    XDG0062 Заданный аргумент находится вне диапазона допустимых
> значений. Имя параметра: index    wpf_photo_viewer    D:\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Visual Studio
> Projects\wpf_photo_viewer\wpf_photo_viewer\MainWindow.xaml

2 ошибка:

> Ошибка    XDG0062 "ContextMenu" не может иметь логического или
> визуального родителя. wpf_photo_viewer    D:\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Visual Studio
> Projects\wpf_photo_viewer\wpf_photo_viewer\MainWindow.xaml

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/contextmenu-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на счёт первой ошибки, но могу помочь со второй.

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="test">
        <MenuItem Header="test"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Этот кусок кода нужно поместить в специальный контейнер <Grid.ContextMenu>. По итогу выглядеть будет следующим образом:

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="test">
        <MenuItem Header="test"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

В другие элементы вставлять контекстное меню нужно аналогичным методом.